# ImageMagick's convert: no images defined

Tags: bash, macos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I tried to execute following command:

```
$ convert 1.png -filter 'Jinc ( +clone -negate -morphology Distance Euclidean -level 50%,-50% )' -morphology Distance Euclidean -compose Plus -composite -level 43%,57% -resize 12.5% 1.png
```

It gives me:

> convert: no images defined `1.png' @
> error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3187.

but it is exists! I tried to execute that command with the debug option enabled:

```
$convert 1.png -filter 'Jinc ( +clone -negate -morphology Distance Euclidean -level 50%,-50% )' -morphology Distance Euclidean -compose Plus -composite -level 43%,57% -resize 12.5% 1.png -debug all
```

I get this output: http://pastebin.com/gsw7KszH

What's wrong with my ImageMagick's configuration? I use the latest macOS.

Comment: Where did you get that command from? What is it trying to do?

Comment: As you have the output image with the same as the input image the problem is probably with the output image and not the input one - try changing the output name to confirm that. On a Linux type system you need to escape ( & ) with a \ is that the same on a mac? But as Mark says the code looks a bit odd as well.

Comment: Please check package: Ghostscript. If you don't have this:```brew install ghostscript```

Comment: Ghost Script install did NOT solve this on OSX.

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it by making the output file name different from the input name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try specifying the filename after the [composite operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#composite), something like this:

```
$ convert 1.png \
   -filter 'Jinc ( +clone -negate -morphology Distance Euclidean -level 50%,-50% )' \
   -morphology Distance Euclidean \
   -compose Plus \
   -composite 1.png \
   -level 43%,57% \
   -resize 12.5% 1.png
```

Comment: I believe you are mistaken in your assertion that `-composite` requires a filename. It merely carries out whatever operation was defined by the preceding `-compose` operator and leaves the result in the image stack.